# Howto implement "beans" and "bean mapping" code?

Tags: java, data-structures, javabeans

We have "beans" that are meant to be serialized to JSON, to be then returned to our (vue.js based) UI layer. So far, my beans look like this:

```
public class ExampleBean {
  private final int id;
  private final String name;
  public ExampleBean(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id; ...
  }
  // getter for all fields
}
```

They are instantiated by some mapper:

```
public ExampleBean map(SomeInternalThing foo)  {
   int id = getIdFromFoo(foo);
   String name = doSomethingElse(foo.itsBar());
   return new ExampleBean(id, name);
}
```

I then have some unit tests (for the mapper):

```
@Test
public void testGetId() {
  ... do some mocking setup so that the mapper can do its job
  assertThat(mapperUnderTest.map(someFoo).getId(), is(5));
}
```

The main advantage of this approach is that bean objects are immutable (and the compiler tells me when I forgot to initialize a field).

But: the number of fields for that bean keeps increasing. That `SomeInternalThing` context has maybe 30 to 50 "properties", and the number of fields required in the bean ... went from 3 to 5 to 8 by now.

What is really "killing" me is the fact that the *mapping* code is doing different things for each required field. Which requires me to have more and more "common" mock specifications to deal with.

By now I am wondering if there are *better* choices to implement such "data only objects".

Comment: I like [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/), and I use it to map JPA entities to / from DTOs. We use the DTOs in the view layer. With MapStruct you can auto-generate the mappers, and use annotations to customize if necessary. Not sure how well it works with immutable DTOs, however.

Comment: what about transfer the logic of the mapper methods and using a really dump mapper logic? this would result in simpler tests for the mapper and simpler tests for the logic in my opinion.

Comment: You have to map many classes that contains many fields with different names. The mappers are not the real problem. You need them because the model is designed like that. Or else you should rework all model classes. But is it possible? With the actual model, I think that mocking the mapping tasks seems expensive, too expensive. Maybe you should test the mapper in integration with the actual class that uses it. It would make mapper to be tested multiple times but which is the value to isolate them if it makes your test classes complex to read and hard  to maintain ?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer lombok ( https://projectlombok.org/ ), when creating data objects. It gets rid of the boilerplate code. You should take a look into the "@Builder" and "@Data" annotation.

Since using lombok is always a team decision, you could start by implementing the builder-pattern by yourself (for such data-objects).

This enables you to set every property seperately, and test every property individually.

That beeing said you probably shouldn't use a constructor with every field.
(see @AllArgsConstructor in lombok)
As you can see here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) beans should have a public default constructor

Comment: I agree that Lombok would probably solve my problem, as switching to a language like Kotlin or Scala that allow to get there with less boilerplate ... but alas, no chances of getting Lombok into our tool chain. So I appreciate your input, but it doesn't help *me* ;-|

Comment: Well, thats sad, but implementing the builder-pattern is still an option

Comment: I think my problem is less the bean itself - but the fact that **all** mapping happens at once inside the mapper.

Comment: Imho this would be the correct approach.. maybe you can split up your data object as you would in data-normalisation approaches. eg. A person has a name, surname, street, house-number -> you would normalise this by giving the Person an adress-reference (Person: {name, surname, adress} + Adress:{street, number}), but I guess sometimes this is not practical